# Bind Usercontrol to scrollbar wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, scrollbar

I'm having a `UserControl` which I'm going to use as a Find/Replace UserControl, like the one in Visual studio.

I'm placing this `UserControl` on top of a `TextBox`.

Users are able to zoom in and out in the `TextBox`, which makes the `ScrollBar` and text smaller/bigger.

So my question:
Is it possible to bind my `UserControl` to the ScrollBar's width?

(I could of course listen to the zoom event and calculate the width, but I would like an easier and better approach)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by:
Comparing `TextEditor.TextArea.ActualWidth` to `TextEditor.ActualWidth`, every time the `ScrollBar` became visible and when the user zoomed. The difference was used to updated the margin of my `UserControl`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
<UserControl Name="uc" Width="{Binding ElementName=scrollBar, Path=ActualWidth}" />
```